# If Multi-Window Lifecycle affect activity lifecycle in android N?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I am working on a application in which I have to provide Multi-Window Support. So I build my application with the `N Preview SDK`. But conceptually I am not clear if `Multi-Window Lifecycle` affect `Activity Lifecycle` in Android N?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html#lifecycle):

> In multi-window mode, only the activity the user has most recently interacted with is active at a given time. This activity is considered topmost. All other activities are in the **paused state**, even if they are visible. However, the system gives these paused-but-visible activities higher priority than activities that are not visible. If the user interacts with one of the paused activities, that activity is resumed, and the previously topmost activity is paused.